# Trade Me API - OAuth before API access

Tags: java, api, oauth

I'm using a Trade Me API. Which requires OAuth access tokens according application registered with it. So i have got OAuth access tokens. I have URL of API, all the parameters and values. But I don't understand how to get started. It is obvious that I need to use access tokens but don't understand where and how to use them. As we cant pass them into URL.
I'm using this API : 
http://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-reference/my-trade-me-methods/retrieve-your-sold-items/

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the API documentation page you provided in your question, there is a Request Builder. This allows you to generate an  API request by filling in the form provided and clicking Send Request.

If you were to capture the HTTP requet generated by the browser when you submit this form using an application such as [Fidler](http://fiddler2.com/), you could determine the correct format for the request, and then generate similarly formatted requests from within your own application.

You might also want to check out the [OAuth](http://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-overview/authentication-authorisation/oauth/) page of the Trade Me Developer API reference which explains how OAuth authentication should be performed for the Trade Me API

Sorry I can't be of more direct assistance, as I'm not a Java developer.